# Calling Javascript Confirm from ASP Classic/VBScript

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic

I am attempting to call a confirm popup from asp classic. Is there a way I can get this Javascript code to execute? It is currently not being called/executed. I need a popup to appear allowing the user to confirm if they want to clear an assignment or not. Thanks!

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<!--#include file="content/securityheader.asp"-->
<!--#include file="connection.inc"-->
<!--#include file="connectionxref.inc"-->
<!--#include file="securityheader.asp"-->
<!--#include file="connectionSQL.inc"-->

<% 'SQL SECURITY CODE
    function dbencodeStr(str)
        thestr = trim(replace(str,"'","&#39;"))
        thestr = trim(replace(thestr,"""","&#34;"))
        thestr = trim(replace(thestr,"<","&lt;"))
        thestr = trim(replace(thestr,">","&gt;"))
        thestr = trim(replace(thestr,vbCRLF,"<BR>"))
        dbencodeStr = thestr
    end function
%>
<script language = "javascript"  runat="server">
function clearAssignment(assignmentID,relno,docrecid)
{
if (confirm("This is the last assignment for this relationship.")){
    window.location.assign("procclearassignmentprompt.asp?assignmentID="+assignmentID+"&relno="+relno+"&docrecid="+docrecid);
    }
}
</script>
<%
Server.ScriptTimeout=3600

'------------------------------
Function getName(str)
index = instr(str," ")
if index > 0 then
str = trim(mid(str,1,index))
end if
getName = str
End Function
'------------------------------

on error resume next

assignmentID = dbencodeStr(request.Querystring("assignmentID"))
docid = dbencodeStr(request.Querystring("docrecid"))
relno = dbencodeStr(request.Querystring("relno"))
thedate = now()

count = 1
'Check if this is the last assignment for relationship
strSQL = "select count(distinct reldocassignments.id) from reldocnotes inner join reldocassignments on reldocnotes.docid=reldocassignments.docid where relno = '"&relno&"' and reldocassignments.activeflag=1"
Set rs = objConnection.Execute(strSQL, ,adCmdText)
    arr = rs.GetRows()
    rows = UBound(arr,2)
    for i = 0 to rows       
        count = trim(arr(0,i))
    next
if count = 1 then
Response.Write "Calling =" & clearAssignment(assignmentID,relno,docrecid) & "."
else
    if docid <> "" Then
        ''''Close any open assignments for the document
        strSQL = "update RelDocAssignments set activeflag = 0, closedOn = getdate() where docid = '"&docid&"' and ID = '"&assignmentID&"';"
        Set rs = objConnection.Execute(strSQL, ,adCmdText)
    end if
Response.write(strSQL)


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

objConnection.close
set objConnection = nothing
objConnection2.close
set objConnection2 = nothing
objConnection3.close
set objConnection3 = nothing

Response.Redirect "relDetails.asp?relNo=" & relno
end if

%>
Count = <%=count%>
```

Comment: Server-side code runs in its entirety before the output is passed to your visitors browsers: it is not run interactively at all, so it doesn't mean anything to "call" a client-side function from server-side code. Fundamentally, all your `.asp` file does is generate text to the client.

Comment: He's actually calling a server-side function from server-side code. There's nothing happening on the client at all here. But yes, I think there's some confusion as to how server-side vs client-side works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have implied, you need to have the confirm JavaScript client side,

So

1. Remove the `runat="server"` for that JavaScript so it runs client side instead.
2. To call that function client side change

   ```
   Response.Write "Calling =" & clearAssignment(assignmentID,relno,docrecid) & "."
   ```

   to

   ```
   Response.Write "<script language='javascript'>clearAssignment(" & assignmentID & "," & relno & "," & docrecid & ")</script>"
   ```